# VBA arrays and calculate using true/false condition

Tags: arrays, vba, sorting

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIR5i.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/61muw.png)

Dear all! Please help, I am trying to sort using an array in VBA.
 I am new to arrays, thus i literally do not know how to start the code. If the entire explanation is too tedious, i will greatly appreciate if you all can consulate on the most optimum framework to use in this context.

1. As shown in the picture, the desire output i wish to achieve is the 
   serial number and the condition will appear as TRUE.
2. The program will then run through all the TRUE condition and give me    the maximum output of outcome($) respectively for each in
       description    and give me the final output.

Comment: This looks like summarization/aggregation - you could do this using a pivot table.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your suggestion! I was thinking of sorting them into a single group and then do a specific action through analyzing this group of strings.

Answer (score 0):

you could achieve it without VBA as follows:

- assuming data in column A:E (as per your screenshots)
- place in G1: `=COUNTA(G2:G22)-COUNTBLANK(G2:G22)`
- place in G2: `=IF(AND($E$2:$E$22="TRUE",COUNTIF($A$1:$A2,A2)=1),A2,"")` and fill down
- place in H2: `=IF($G2<>"",MAX(H$1:H1)+1,"")` and fill down
- place in I2: `=MAX(IF($A$2:$A$22=A2,IF($E$2:$E$22="TRUE",IF(COUNTIF($A$1:$A2,A2)=1,$B$2:$B$22,""),""),""))`, leave the cell by CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER to have it an array formula. copy it and paste it from the cell underneath to the end of data row
- place in K2: `=IF(ROWS(K$1:K1)<$G$1,INDEX($G$2:$G$22,MATCH(ROWS(K$1:K1),$H$2:$H$22,0)),"")` and fill down
- place in L2: `=IF(ROWS(K$1:K1)<$G$1,INDEX($I$2:$I$22,MATCH(ROWS(K$1:K1),$H$2:$H$22,0)),"")` and fill down

this will give you a result as per the following image

[image]

with wanted list in columns K:L

of course you have to change all `22` rows indexes to your actual data last row index